# does laptop and pc have different booting files

Tags: boot, partitioning, boot-partition, partition-copy

I have recently bought a new hard disc and copied all my booting data are files into my new hard disc so that my new hard disc is also bootable and it is working fine with my PC but when I use that hard disc in my laptop my laptop screen is not turning.

Does it means my laptop have any problem or laptop and PC have different booting files.

What can be done to solve this problem

Comment: Depending on the age of both the machines they may well have different boot methods and expect different partitioning schemes. Google "BIOS Vs UEFI"

Comment: You also need the correct devices drivers loaded.

Comment: Where can i get my laptop's boot files since its default hard disk have been broken.

Comment: You don't say what OS you're using, so I'll assume it's Windows. In my experience, booting a Windows installation created on one computer on another computer is tricky at best; Windows installations are too tied to computer-specific device drivers, as David notes. There are also BIOS vs. EFI issues, as Mokubai says. Overall, your best bet is to do a clean install on the new disk using the computer in which you intend to use it. You can then copy your personal data files over.

Comment: @RodSmith  yes i am using window, the thing is that hard drive is working fine in pc but not in laptop, when i connect it to my laptop it says no boot devices are found, so what can i do to make it work

Comment: Where can i found the boot files required for my laptop, since laptop hardisk have been broken so cant use it to copy from it.